# Adding appendix to table of content without making it appear in the document

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I am working with `article` class and I want to mention two appendices in my table of content, without making an actual appendix in the document itself. Also, I want that these entries in the TOC will not refer to any page (obviously, since there are no appendices in the document to refer to). How can I make these things happen?

EDIT:

Here's (a simplified version of) the code I use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}

\lstset{style=mystyle,language=Python}

\title{title}
\author{bla}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
bla bla

\end{abstract}
\pagebreak
\tableofcontents

\pagebreak
\section{sections}
bla bla

\pagebreak
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{someitem}
something

\end{thebibliography}

\pagebreak

\appendix

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{Appendix One}{}{}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{Appendix Two}{}{}}

\addtocontents{toc}{Appendix One}

\end{document}
```

EDIT2:

I have found a workaround using the following line of code, which is an extension to a suggestion in a comment:

`\addtocontents{toc}{\textcolor{white}{}\\ \textbf{Appendix A: bla bla}\\\textcolor{white}{}\\ \textbf{Appendix B: bla bla}}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE: Try `\addtocontents{toc}{Appendix One\par}` and the 'same' for the second one, at the end of the document, most likely. This way there will be no hyperlink or page reference, if needed

Comment: Thank you! This works, however the formatting is wrong; "Appendix one" looks like a subsection now, which is not what I was looking for.

Comment: Sorry, your `workaround` is not really sensible. The reason, why it does not work for you is the `\pagebreak` before `\appendix`. Since `\appendix` does not print anything and the `\addtocontents` - calls do nothing there as well which would  contribute to an output, the code is never used there. Use `\appendix\null\addtocontents...` as I have proposed and it should work

Answer (score 3):

If a specific format should be maintained, i.e. like a section entry, use

`\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{Appendix One}{}{}}`

The first empty `{}` pair is usually filled by `\addcontentsline` to hold the page number, the empty `{}` pair is used by `hyperref` for the hyperanchor. If `hyperref` is not included, the 2nd `{}` does no harm there.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents


\section{First section}

\appendix

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{Appendix One}{}{}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{Appendix Two}{}{}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If a numbered format is requested, `\numberline{}` could be applied as well, all cast into one simple macro:

`\phantomappendix*` will add the title only

`\phantomappendix` will add the title and a preceding number.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\newcounter{phantomappendix}
\renewcommand{\thephantomappendix}{\Alph{phantomappendix}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\phantomappendix}{sm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{#2}{}{}}
  }{%
    \refstepcounter{phantomappendix}% Just in case we want to refer to it
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{\protect\numberline{\thephantomappendix}#2}{}{}}
  }%
}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First section}
\appendix

\phantomappendix*{Appendix One}
\phantomappendix{Appendix Two}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, the two appendices do not show up in my TOC when I follow these instructions. Any idea on what might be the issue here?

Comment: @Tyron: Have you compiled twice? ;-)

Comment: I have, still nothing.

Comment: @Tyron: Are you using the `article` class really? My screen shot proves that I am correct here

Comment: I guess? \documentclass{article} is the first line in my latex code.

Comment: @Tyron: Then add your code to your question above

Comment: I have done so (even though it doesn't look nice).